# React, undefined is not an object - json data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to loop through an array of data. I have followed a guide but unfortunately I'm not having the same success. The data file looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
export default  [
{ id: 1, lk:593458, ld:18033, status: 'Open'},
{ id: 2, lk:593388, ld:18036, status: 'Closed'},
{ id: 3, lk:593420, ld:18047, status: 'Open'}
]
```

and the file I'm trying to work with the data in like this:

```
  import data from './data';

  const {data} = this.props;
  let markers = this.data.map(id => (
```

No matter what I get the error "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.data.map'. Where am I screwing up? Thanks

Comment: What does your second snippet mean? What is `this` there?

Comment: It looks like you're reassigning the `data` import with your destructuring?

Comment: Are you talking about let markers = this.data.map(id => ? I have tried some different versions but it doesn't work. It's the same if I remove it and have data.map. Also, I'm very new to react so I don't understand what you mean with destructuring @CertainPerformance

Comment: @J.Doe it's not about destructuring. You've imported the `data` in the first line then never used it.

Comment: @J.Doe you need to provide the component so that people helped you, at the moment you posted random 3 lines of code which make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot re-declare an imported variable.

```
import data from './data';

const {data} = this.props;
```

The second line re-declares the `data` variable which you already imported from the `./data` module.

You can either use the `import x as y from './module` syntax in order to rename your imported module or to not use the destructuring on line 2: `const _data = this.props.data`.

Comment: Why would they use `this.props.data` at all given data is in `data` already?

Comment: I also don't know the context of what the OP is doing. They might need to use the `this.props.data` value for some reason.

Comment: That's what they cannot understand actually, and I think the answers before them providing their component (not just random lines) and explaining what they are doing/expecting make more harm not help.

Comment: You are right @zerkms, I don't know what I'm doing and I don't understand what you and tsvetan are talking about. I'm working really hard to figure out what I'm doing though. I am thankful for your help though

Comment: @J.Doe it's alright, no one is blaming you - learning is a natural process. But to make your question answerable you need to provide more context: at least your component + intentions.

Answer (score 0):

`this.data` would be undefined at that point?

You can do:

`data.map(e => {})`

Comment: Your second option would make my code look like this? I am getting unexpected token error while doing that unfortunately. const {data} = this.props;

    let markers = this.props.data.map(id => {} ( //code to be executed

Comment: Oh! Just realised you're re-declaring the variable. I'm sure you can see an error: `Duplicate declaration "data"`? Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import to know your options to fix that specific problem.

Comment: Simplest option: `this.props.data = data`, but there's other options too

Comment: @MagdKudama what's the point to mutate `this.props`? Is it even allowed?

Comment: In the code I cannot see if it's a React component or not. In a React component context, props are immutable, yes.

Comment: @zerkms edited comment, removed assignment to props, not to confuse the OP